# Representing rotation per second in 3D

Tags: math, 3d

What's a good way to represent 3D rotation per second that can handle more than 180° of rotation and is easy/efficient to apply with a time delta? Quaternions are great for orientation but fail to represent more than 180° of rotation and aren't too straight-foward to combine with a time delta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use axis-angle representation, it's quite similar to quaternions, so you can easily convert between them, it's also easy to read/understand/interpolate and don't have the 180deg limit.

You have to be careful with conversions to quaternions though. You can't convert your target rotation like `rotate by 180deg` to quaternion, but you can interpolate it for current frame and convert only current delta if it's less than 180deg.

Comment: In regards to the second paragraph of your answer: Can't I just multiply my angle/s of rotation around my axis by the number of seconds, turn that into a quaternion, and then add that quaternion to my object's current orientation? The resulting orientation should still be correct.

Comment: I'm sorry if I've misguided you, I just meant what you've said - that you can't use quaternions to represent rotations > 180deg. You CAN compute a quaternion for '720deg' rotation and use it for rendering, but you CAN'T interpolate from '0' to '720deg' using quaternion - for this case interpolate axis-angle representation.